# How to scroll elements on canvas in different states and in different containers and not move others

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, state, move, dynamic

I generate panels dynamically and put them in other states in that way so in one state you have a list of panels on the left and one big panel on the right for example in one state and when you click on the list on the left (with small panels) that panels takes the places of the big panel and the big one goes back in the place. So I have 50 panels on the left and i want to scroll them down but I don't want to big panel to go down with them I want it fixed.[image]
this is where I got and I don't know how to do that
here is my code:

```
enter code here
```

protected function canvas1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

```
            blurEffect= new BlurEffect(myBlur,myUnBlur);

            listEventsResult.token=eventService.listEvent();
            blurEffect.initFilter(event);


            panels=generatePanels(panelNumber);
            var vBox:VGroup= new VGroup();


            states=statesList.toArray();

            trace("stavi sequence i sostojba e"+ states[0].toString());

            for(var i:int=0; i<panelNumber ;i++)        // get panel from list panels and set states
            {
                 addChild(panels.getItemAt(i) as Panel);    
                (states[i] as State).overrides=[ new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"x",110), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"y",0),
                    new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"width",widthBigPanel), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"height",heightBigPanel)
                    //,new AddChild(g2,(panels.getItemAt(k) as Panel))
                    //,new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"scaleZ",110)
                ];
                trace("vlegov override za new state");
                var yy:int=0;


                for(var k:int=0;k<panelNumber;k++)
                {
                    trace("menuvam state: yy = " + yy);
                    if(k!=i){
                        vBox.addChild(panels.getItemAt(k) as Panel);
                        (states[i] as State).overrides = (states[i] as State).overrides.concat([ new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"x",x), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"y",yy),
                            new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"width",widthPanel), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"height",heightPanel)
                        //,new AddChild(g1,(panels.getItemAt(k) as Panel))
                        ]);
                        yy+=110;
                    }
                }

                for(z=0; z<(states[i] as State).overrides.length; ++z){
                    var tempSetProperty:SetProperty= (states[i] as State).overrides[z] as SetProperty;
                    trace("\nname: " + tempSetProperty.name);
                    trace("target: " + tempSetProperty.target);
                    trace("value: " + tempSetProperty._value);
                }


                setCurrentState("state0");
                addChild(vBox);
            }

            //sequence.targets=panels.toArray();
            t1.targets=panels.toArray();

        }
```

Comment: If you just addChild the panels on the canvas it works but you scroll them all! in this way like it is shown it doesn't work because of the vBox that I try to add...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your regular scrolling, but add a vertical scroll bar listener,  scroll="myScroll(event), that repositions the large panel as scrolling occurs (using something like the original x,y values of the panel and the verticalScrollPosition property).

Alternatively, you could add a second canvas on top of the first one, and sets its background to transparent. Place the large panel on the transparent canvas so it doesnt scroll (and put it back to the original canvas when scrolling completes if that suits).

Both of these are heavy(ish) on processing (especially the transparent canvas).

Comment: well I cant get to work it out how to move from one container to an other one because I already predefine them in what state what panel to be to accomplished that moving on the right place like a sort. I get the scroll position from the parent canvas and I put it as a y coordinate in given state for the big panel and is bindable but id doesn;t work????

Comment: In what way is it not working? To debug it, dont use bindings, but rather call a function on the scroll event, and set the coordinates of the panel in that function. You can then set a breakpoint in that function and make sure that the values are as expected. You may need to use validateNow() after setting the position, but im not sure.